# Embed a html page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to embed a full html page into an angular view. I have tested the pages as static text and those render correctly. But when i try to use placehoder

```
  <object data="'{{gsdCtrl.gevaarlijkeStofDetail.Risk}}'"></object>
```

it doesn't show anything.

The placeholder does show the html as clear text when i use it in a normal div:

```
 <div>{{gsdCtrl.gevaarlijkeStofDetail.Risk}}</div>
```

I'm using  AngularJS v1.2.10

Why doesn't the HTML page show when using a placeholder?

Thanks in advance,

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

In angular you need to use:

```
$scope.Risk =   $sce.trustAsHtml(ctrl.gevaarlijkeStofDetail.Risk);

 <div ng-bind-html="Risk">
```